How do I set the account on my msalInstance when I already have an access token, but I don't want the user to log in
The happy flow: A user logs in.
I have a react application that requires users to log in with active directory. I am using the msal-react package. When the user opens my website, he ends on a log-in screen, clicks the login button, and the following code works wonders:
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  await instance.loginRedirect(authRequest);

Voilà and I am done. Now any time I need a new token, I can use the acquireTokenSilent() method, and I can see account information from my instance.getAccount() method.
Where problems arise: Public QR codes.
I want a person to be able to scan a QR code, and land on a particular page. No login required. His permissions will be limited by the back-end. All my back-end calls still require an Azure access_token, so my idea is the following:

I've created a "public" user with a very strong password and very restricted permissions.
I've properly encrypted and encoded the login credentials for this user into MY_BASE64_TOKEN
After scanning qr code, the user lands on https://frontend.com?t={MY_BASE64_TOKEN}.
The frontend calls the backend like so https://mybackend.com/api/auth?myToken={MY_BASE64_TOKEN}
The backend decrypts the password, calls azure ROPC login, and returns an azure_access token to the frontend.
CHALLENGE: I now have access tokens in my frontend. Hurrah! But it would be so nice if I could now use all my msal logic. This way, tracking active accounts and acquiring new tokens would already be handled for me. If there was a method like msalInstance.setAccountByJwtToken(access_token), or something, then everything could be set. As far as I understand it, the only way for msal to set the account is to force a user through a login flow.

Am I making this too difficult? Or is there a simply approach I am overlooking?
An attempt at tricking msal
I've read the documentation figured I could maybe trick msal into thinking I've already logged in. My idea was that I could retrieve the information about my account, and then call msalInstance.setAccount(myAccount), then set the JWT token in the cache, and then call acquireTokenSilently, but I couldn't get it to work. Here is the code more or less. To be honest, messing with the internal cache of msal seems like a hard and brittle thing. Something I want to avoid. Is there an easier way?
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAzureToken = async () => {
      const myBase64Token = searchParams.get('t');
      if (myBase64Token) {
          const azureToken = await api.fetchAzureToken(myBase64Token);
          const decodedToken: AzureAccessJwtPayload = jwtDecode(azureToken.accessToken);
          const account = {
            username: decodedToken.emails[0],
            name: decodedToken.name,
            localAccountId: decodedToken.oid,
            tenantId: 'correct_tenant_id',
            homeAccountId: `correct_home_account_id`,
            environment: 'correct_environment',
          };
          
          msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
        
          // I got this from an AI, but the cacheStorage method does not exist.
          await msalInstance.cacheStorage.setItem(`${account.homeAccountId}-${account.environment}-accesstoken-your_client_id-your_tenant_id-your_scopes`, azureToken.accessToken);
          await msalInstance.cacheStorage.setItem(`${account.homeAccountId}-${account.environment}-refreshtoken-your_client_id-your_tenant_id-your_scopes`, azureToken.refreshToken);
          await msalInstance.cacheStorage.setItem(`${account.homeAccountId}-${account.environment}-idtoken-your_client_id-your_tenant_id-`, idToken); // I don't have this

          // Acquire a new token silently
          try {
            const silentRequest = {
              scopes: [process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SCOPE!, "offline_access"],
              account: account
            };
            const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
            console.log("Token acquired successfully:", response);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error acquiring token:", error);
          }
      }
    };
    fetchAzureToken();
  }, [searchParams]);



set the JWT token in the cache, and then call acquireTokenSilently, but I couldn’t get it to work.


Try in another approach to avoid directly manipulating MSAL’s internal cache. Instead, use a combination of MSAL’s methods to set the account and token in a more reliable way.

Custom authentication provider:
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "your_client_id",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id",
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const CustomAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAzureToken = async () => {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const myBase64Token = urlParams.get("t");

      if (myBase64Token) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://mybackend.com/api/auth?myToken=${myBase64Token}`);
        const azureToken = await response.json();
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(azureToken.accessToken);

        const account = {
          homeAccountId: `some_unique_id.${decodedToken.oid}`,
          environment: "login.microsoftonline.com",
          tenantId: decodedToken.tid,
          username: decodedToken.preferred_username,
        };

        msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);

        msalInstance.getTokenCache().writeTokens({
          accessToken: azureToken.accessToken,
          refreshToken: azureToken.refreshToken,
          idToken: azureToken.idToken,
          expiresIn: azureToken.expiresIn,
          account,
        });

        try {
          const silentRequest = {
            scopes: ["your_api_scope"],
            account: account,
          };
          const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
          console.log("Token acquired successfully:", response);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error acquiring token:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchAzureToken();
  }, []);

  return children;
};

export default CustomAuthProvider;

CAP in application:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import CustomAuthProvider from "./CustomAuthProvider";
import App from "./App";
import { msalInstance } from "./CustomAuthProvider";

ReactDOM.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <CustomAuthProvider>
      <App />
    </CustomAuthProvider>
  </MsalProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);




Thank you, but the method .writeTokens() does not appear to be available on the ITokenCache instance. Do you have a link to the documentation where you got this from?
I am using:
"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.15.0",
"@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.17",
